# Why does a nested HTML element make my CSS jump?

Tags: css, html, positioning

Here's a puzzle. Basic page, one element:

http://jsfiddle.net/PZj6t/

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>​
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #666;
}
​
```

That one looks how I want, with the #container neatly flush to the top. But when I add a nested element:

http://jsfiddle.net/PZj6t/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <nav id="topnav"></nav>
</div>​
```

CSS (new):

```
#topnav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 30px 0;
    background-color: red;
}
​
```

The container jumps down. It seems that the margin-top from #topnav is somehow being passed to the container, and now the page has a scrollbar I don't want. (I'm testing in Chrome.) How do I prevent this?

(As a further mystery, if I add `border: 1px solid white;` to the #container's CSS, the jump disappears. Which would be fine, except that also adds two pixels worth of undesirable scroll to the page.)

Comment: You're adding a margin to something that is already 100% high. Use padding instead.

Comment: @Diodeus The nav isn't 100% height, the container is. The container has no vertical margin declared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to a feature of CSS called margin collapsing. If there is no padding or border on a parent element, the parent and its child's margins "collapse" to the greater value of the two and is essentially applied to the parent.

For your situation, I would suggest simply adding an additional inner wrap within the container, and throwing some padding on it to simulate the margin effect you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/PZj6t/3/

Anything within the `#inner` div or below should behave as you expect, as margins only collapse when they are at the edge of their parent (and no padding or borders are present).

Comment: Interesting feature -- I knew margins collapsed for adjacent elements, but I never noticed it also applied to nested elements. In all my years as a developer it never affected my work until now.

Answer (score 1):

```
display:inline-block;
```

On Your nav element appears will fix this. Its to do with margin-collapsing see [here](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing) for more detail.

Comment: This certainly seems like the simplest solution, although I have to adjust my margins on other elements after the #topnav.

Answer (score 1):

Jblasco is correct, this is a neater solution though: http://jsfiddle.net/PZj6t/4/

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    margin: -1px auto 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top:1px;
    background-color: #666;
}
#topnav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 29px 0 30px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Adding any kind of padding with `height: 100%` will result in a vertical scrollbar on the page. Maybe if he used `display: border-box` on `#container` this would be an okay solution.

Comment: Also by `display: border-box` I meant `box-sizing: border-box`. I still feel like messing with `box-sizing` or using negative margins is kind of sketchy though.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid CSS3 solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #666;
    border:1px solid;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PZj6t/12/

```
Update:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PZj6t/1/
apply `display:inline-block;` on both `container` and `topnav`