# Why is there no margin at the bottom of my ul?

Tags: html, css, margin

No elements are floated, but only the bottom margin is displayed outside of the containing div. What is the reason for this and how can I fix it so that the margin is on the ul, inside its container?

http://jsfiddle.net/krcoxq0v/1/

html

```
<div class="box">
    <h2>Title</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
div {
    background:#aaa;
    width:300px;
}
ul {
    margin:25px;
    padding:0;
    background:#ddd;
}
li {
    list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a nested HTML element make my CSS jump?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9519147/901048)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden;` to the top level `div`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krcoxq0v/2/)

```
div {
    background:#aaa;
    width:300px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
ul {
    margin:25px;
    padding:0;
    background:#ddd;
}
li {
    list-style:none;
}
```

This will enforce a [block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

> A block formatting context is a part of a visual CSS rendering of a
>   Web page. It is the region in which the **layout of block boxes occurs**
>   and in which floats interact with each other.

Comment: Note that this adds a margin to the top of the `h2` at the same time -- or rather, it moves that margin inside the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden;` in your div css.

Comment: @Aibrean - How doesn't it? It's short, it's sweet, and it's an attempt at an answer.

Comment: @Aibrean It is an answer. It's not even a terrible answer.  When we say "Not an answer", we don't mean "Not a good answer" we mean "Is not an attempt to address the issue the OP is having with some sort of solution"

Comment: My english is bad sry, so I just want to give an answer without fault.